# Ajax jquery delete

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, django

Hi I am using django framework with sql database. I want to store the values into the database and delete it with ajax post method. I can store it into the database but I don't know how to write code for delete.
models.py

```
class personaldetails(models.Model):
    fname=models.CharField(max_length=30)
    lname=models.CharField(max_length=30)
    email=models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

views.py

```
def personalinformation(request):
    if request.POST:
        personaldetails(fname=request.POST['input1'],lname=request.POST['input2'],email=request.POST['input4']).save()
        p=personaldetails.objects.all()
        print "saved"
        s=""
        for person in p:
            if person:          
                s+="<tr><td>"+str(person.id)+"</td><td>"+person.fname+"</td><td>"+person.lname+"</td><td>"+person.email+"</td><td><input type='button' value='delete'></td></tr>"
            # <td>"+person.lname+"</td><td>"+person.email</td>

        return HttpResponse(s)
    return render(request,"itechdisplay.html")
```

itechdisplay.html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $('#submit1').click(function(e){
                    e.preventDefault;
                    $.post("/personalinformation/",$("#testform").serialize()).done(function(x){
                        $('#ajaxbox').html("<tr><th>id</th><th>firstname</th><th>lastname</th><th>email</th><th>Delete</th></tr>"+x);
                    }); 
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="testform" >{% csrf_token %}
            Firstname:<input type="text" id="firstname" name="input1"><br>
            Lastname:<input type="text" id="lastname" name="input2"><br>
            e-mail:<input type="text" id="email" name="input4"><br>
        </form>
        <div >
            <table border="1px" id="ajaxbox" ></table>
        </div>
        <a href="#" id="submit1" >save</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

We can delete it with the help of id only.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

views.py:

```
def remove_element(request, elem_id):
    success = False
    try:
        elem = SomeObject.objects.get(id=elem_id)
        elem.delete()
        success = True
    except:
        pass
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps({'success': True}), mimetype='application/json')
```

javascript:

```
function removeElement(remove_url){
    $.ajax({
        url: remove_url,
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json'
    });
```

html:

```
<a href='#' onclick='javascript:removeElement(\"{% url 'remove_elem_url_name' element.id %}\"); return false'>Delete elem</a>
```

urls:

```
url(r'^remove_elem/(?P<elem_id>[0-9]+)/$', 'some_app.views.remove_element', name='remove_elem_url_name')
```

You can also pass some message information into json and show it after success ajax call.